# java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code to move a undecorated swing frame but whenever i press my mouse button the following exception appears:

```
java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location
```

Here is my Code

```
   class Gui extends Frame

{

    JFrame frame;
    JLabel label;
    Gui()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        label = new JLabel("...");
        label.setForeground(Color.white);
        //label.setBounds(300,300, 100,30);  
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setSize(30, 30);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setLocation(1550, 1045);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));       
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        listenMouse();



       
        



    }

    public void listenMouse()
    {
        MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
            int lastX, lastY;
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                lastX = e.getXOnScreen();
                lastY = e.getYOnScreen();
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getXOnScreen();
                int y = e.getYOnScreen();
                // Move frame by the mouse delta
                frame.setLocation(getLocationOnScreen().x + x - lastX,
                        frame.getLocationOnScreen().y + y - lastY);
                lastX = x;
                lastY = y;
            }
        };
        frame.addMouseListener(ma);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(ma);


    }
```

Could it be that the window is too small or the position where it is is problematic? Is on taskbar already off screen?

Comment: remove sellocation and setLocationByPlatform(true) and check whether error still there.

Comment: still happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `extend Frame` - you have two window based classes, `Gui`, which extends from `Frame`, not a good idea on multiple accounts*, and `frame` which is an instance of `JFrame`.

```
frame.setLocation(getLocationOnScreen().x + x - lastX,
        frame.getLocationOnScreen().y + y - lastY);
```

is then trying to set the location of the `JFrame` based on the location of the `Frame`, which hasn't been realised on the screen.

So, the short answer is, you're confusing yourself.

*`Frame` is an AWT based component and in this context, would not be a good starting point.  Extending from top level containers, like `Frame` is generally discouraged, as you are not adding any new functionality to the class, it locks you into a single use case (reduces re-use) and top level containers tend to be much more complex structures and can really mess with you in ways you might not be expecting*